# Prevent background scroll & Jumping to top on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On our mobile site, when clicking the hamburger icon in the top right I want the drop-down menu to appear and be scrollable, without the background scrolling. I have written javascript to set the body to `fixed` when you click the menu icon, however, this results in the website jumping to the top of the page. This is not what I want, I would like for it so that when the user clicks on the menu button, the background page stays where it is and does not jump to the top.

Below is the code that I have already tried for this.

Javascript

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".x-btn-navbar").on("click", function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("noScroll");
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.noScroll {
    position: fixed;
}
```

**EDIT** Here is the website: http://s2br5s5r3.gb-02.live-paas.net

Comment: Please provide more complete example. Like code pen, or code snippet so we can recreate issue and provide help.

Comment: @wired just provided website link.

Comment: did you try preventdefault(); ?

Comment: @ShahilM Yes I have tried that and it just stop the jumping to top, but allows the scrolling in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`href="#"` makes page going top, give correctly url ex: `href="https://www.google.com/"` then the problem of going top will be solved.

**css**

```
.noScroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    /* position: fixed */ 
}
```

**javascript**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".x-btn-navbar").on("click", function() {
    $("html, body").toggleClass("noScroll");
  });
});
```

then the `<body>` will be unscrollable.

Comment: This is exactly what I told you to do on your last question, but suddenly now it works...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You pointed me towards another question, something that had nothing to do with my own? You told me put in `preventdefault()`. You did not tell me to put in the exact working code like @joy has done...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'll take you not replying as you accepting that you are wrong and we are right?...

Comment: No you can take it that I can't be bothered with people who only want to be spoonfed answers to poor questions which could be solved through 2 minutes of research.

Answer (score 2):

first of all remove the css position fixed from the class no-scroll. That's what is causing the page to jump on top when you click the menu button. After you open the menu it is scrollable as it should, i assume what you want is to prevent the page behind the open menu to be scrolled when the menu is open. Ypu can achieve this with javascript event listeners like so:

```
EventTarget.addEventListener('scroll', noscroll);
```

instead of EventTarget give the body an id and use the event listener to that when the user clicks on the element, but then when they close the menu you should remove the event listener with:

```
EventTarget.removeEventListener()
```

I hope this helps you

Keep in mind though that you have to separate the content of the page from the menu, because if you add the no scroll to the body that will apply also to the menu as long as it is a child of the body